# How do I change this sql query to linq to sql?

Tags: linq

I wrote the query and I want convert it to linq query

```
SELECT     dbo.tblSaman.fldSamanId, dbo.tblFaaliatSaman.FldFaaliatId
FROM         dbo.tblSaman LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.tblFaaliatSaman ON dbo.tblSaman.fldSamanId = dbo.tblFaaliatSaman.fldSamanId
WHERE     (dbo.tblFaaliatSaman.FldFaaliatId IN (3, 4))
```

Comment: What are your IQueryable types called?

Comment: I highly recommend you to try this tool http://www.linqpad.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use something like that:

```
int[] ids = { 3, 4 };
            var items = context.tblSaman.Join(context.tblFaaliatSaman.DefaultIfEmpty().Where(x => ids.Contains(x.FldFaaliatId)), x => x.fldSamanId,
                                  y => y.fldSamanId, (x, y) => new { fldSamanId = x.fldSamanId, FldFaaliatId = y.FldFaaliatId });
```